# Как сделать чтоб закрывалась меню с push notifications?

Tags: java, android, уведомления, android-notification

Я получаю `notification` который содержит 2 кнопки, к этим кнопкам привязаны `pending intent`ы, при нажатии любую из кнопок,`notification` удаляется методом `cancel()` и происходит действие.

Шторка с остальными `notification` должна свернуться, но она не сворачивается...

Но в тоже время у меня к самому `notification` привязан интент и если нажать на сам интент то шторка сворачивается...

Я так понимаю, что разница в том, что на `notification` установлено `setAutoCancel(true)`, но я не могу тоже самое прикрепить на кнопку, поэтому в случае нажатия на нее просто убиваю `notification` методом `cancel()`.

Но как закрыть эту шторку?)

Answer (score 1):

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568754/) для закрытия шторки советуют сделать так:

```
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
context.sendBroadcast(it);
```

Comment: Мне не помогло... Да и сам автор вопроса говорит, что ему это не помогло... Ему подошел другой способ, но мне если честно и другой тоже не подходит...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Может, попробуйте еще один вариант с рефлексией, но для более поздней версии API. См. ответ, отмеченный как верный по ссылке: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434014/

Comment: Да я пробовал, но там тоже не получается...